# Hi, I wanted to locate to an element using mouse hover actions. Linux OS, Selenium-Headless testing, Python. I get element not interactable exception

Tags: python, linux, exception, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

ELEMENT NOT INTERACTABLE EXCEPTION DURING SELENIUM HEADLESS BROWSER TESTING IN LINUX OS, PYTHON CODE USED.

Keyboard actions or mouse actions not working in Linux OS causing element not interactable exception.

On adding this code, element not interactable exception sorted out in Windows OS and was able to perform mouse actions and keyboard actions.

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")      
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
```

Particularly in Linux OS,
Actions class not working due to which move to element or double click is not working in my code.
Keyboard actions not working due to which keys.ENTER or keys.TAB is not working in my code.